# Mosquito MQTT Servidor Windows

Tags: javascript, windows, servidor, websocket, mqtt

estoy intentando crear una conexión al mosquito MQTT en mi servidor de Windows.

he instalado el mosquito en mi servidor, he modificado su archivo conf. para ponerlo en escucha en el puerto y puerto que me interesa pero no consigo crear la conexión de cliente.  Estoy usando javascript.

Estoy usando la siguiente librería:

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/paho-mqtt/1.1.0/paho-mqtt.js

Es la primera vez que intento hacer algo así y no se que puede estar fallando.

¿Alguien podría ayudarme?

Saludos,

Comment: Hola, bienvenido al sitio. Por favor, revisa [¿ Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta ?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Sin proporcionar un [mcve] que reproduzca tu problema de conexión, será difícil que nadie te ayude. Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

Mi problema es el siguiente:

He instalado en un servidor de Windows el Mosquito MQTT v5 como servicio. Además dicho servicio está activo. Se supone que actúa como servidor.

Ahora quiero crear el cliente (en javascript) para poder conectar con dicho servidor.

El código que empleo es el siguiente:

// --- MQTT.js ---- //

```
var client = new Paho.Client(host, port, 'clientId');

client.onConnectionLost = onConnectionLost;
client.onMessageArrived = onMessageArrived;

// connect the client

console.log('connecting MQTT...');

client.connect( { onSuccess: onConnect } );

function onConnect() {

    console.log('Conected');
    client.subscribe('World');
    message = new Paho.Message('Hello');
    message.destinationName = 'World';
    client.send(message);
}

function onConnectionLost(responseObject) {
    if( responseObject.errorCode !== 0) {
        console.log('onConnectionLost: ' + responseObject.errorMessage);
    }
}

function onMessageArrived(message) {
    console.log('onMessageArrived: ' + message.payloadString);
}
```

// ---------------- //

El error que me muestra es el siguiente:

mqtt.js:1054 WebSocket connection to 'ws://host/mqtt' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

Comment: Por favor, no utilices la zona de respuestas para proporcionar información adicional. Esta zona es **solo para respuestas**. [Edita](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/405215/edit) tu pregunta y añade la información que estimes conveniente. Usa el enlace que te proporciono, o el que se encuentra en la parte de abajo de tu pregunta.¿ Te has pasado ya por [El Centro de Ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help) para saber como funciona el sitio ? Un saludo.